# error when input wrong type in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

In struts 2. I define an attribute in my action controller like below:

```
private int row;
public int getRow() {
return row;
}
public void setRow(int row) {
this.row = row;
}
```

How I can process in case: in client, user input row is a string (ex: row='abc'). My action will be have error log:

```
   ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setRow" failed for object 
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1305)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
at     com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
```

I want to process: If row is String -> return row =0
(I dont want to change attribute of row to String type, i still want to keep row is int or Integer )
Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Make it as String, after that validate the given input is int or not.

Comment: to define as String is easy. But i still want to keep it int or Integer. I beleave struts 2 have any way to process it

Comment: But you cant restrict the user to give the string as input. Try to restrict the string by using javascript. for allowing numbers and backspace.

Comment: yes we cant restrict the user to give the string as input, but can we process in Interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Way 1` :

change the `int as String`

```
private String row;

public String getRow()
{
   return row;
}

public void setRow(String row)
{
   this.row = row;
}

private boolean validateRow(String row)
{
  if(isInteger())
    {
      // check the given value as int or Integer.
      return true;
    }
  // show the message invalid
  return false;
}
```

`Way 2` :

Use `javaScript` to allow `only numbers` and `backSpace` try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/)

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```